# Create subheaders in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to create sub-header columns by only using javascript. My data is coming from server so I just want to create columns and subheaders.

So columns I have already created but how to have subheader with only javascript ( css can be there) but not with the help of html that I am not able to get.
[image: Like this]

Can someone help me with this.
this is some demo of table -

[image]

here at top I need to add two subheader with 3 columns

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the structure of data is? This can be easily done with tables or just divs (that are dynamically created in javascript).

Comment: @squGEIm structure of data meaning how it looks or what is type of data I am using?

Comment: What do you mean by "but not with the help of html that I am not able to get." ?

Comment: my html is just have div id but all the formation of elements in page is done in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addSubHeader').click(function() {
    var subHeader =  "<tr><th>3</th><th>4</th>><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr>";
    $(subHeader).appendTo("thead");
  });
 });
```

```css
th {
  text-align:center;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">1</th>
    <th colspan="2">2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbdody>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</tbdody>
</table>
<button id="addSubHeader">
add a subheader</button>
</button>
```